# Django testing, issue with localised error messages

Tags: django, testing, localization

I am making the first steps with using Django localisation, and I have just faced the first difficulty. I am trying to test that something in models works as expected. For invalid input, a specific ValidationError should occur. The code in the test looks like this:

```
try:
    p = ...
    p.full_clean()
    self.fail('Expected exception not raised')
except ValidationError as e:
    dict_err = dict(e)
    self.assertIn('category', dict_err.keys())
    self.assertEqual(len(dict_err.keys()), 1, 'Encountered more than one error')
    self.assertIn('blank', dict_err['category'][0])
```

As long as the site operates in English (`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-uk'`), the caught error looks like this:

```
ValidationError({'category': ['This field cannot be blank.']})
```

To check that I've got exactly *this* ValidationError, I am searching for the work 'blank' in the error message (last line of the code above).

It fails as soon as I switch the site to another language. E.g. for German it looks so:

```
ValidationError({'category': ['Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein.']})
```

Looking for 'blank' obviously fails the test. How could I check the error message? I expect, somewhere deep in Django, there should be a unique identifier of this message (so that Django knows how to translate). But I don't see any traces of it in the error value. I would expect something like

```
self.assertIn(_(id), dict_err['category'][0])
```

would do the trick, if I could guess what `id` should be, and if I understand correctly what `_()` does.

Comment: But you know the supposed id is `'blank'` in this case, so why not `_('blank')`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, because `_('blank')` returns simply `blank`, it is not a message ID. I simply expect that if the word 'blank' is present in the error message, then the error message is most probably the relevant one. If tomorrow the Django project team decides to change 'This field cannot be blank' to 'Blank field is not allowed', it should also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By further trial and error, I've found that for simple messages the message ID is simply the original English message. That is, one can do:

```
...
expected_error = _("This field cannot be blank.")
self.assertIn(expected_error, dict_err['category'][0])
```

or even

```
self.assertEqual(expected_error, dict_err['category'][0])
```

It works then independent of the site language.

For errors using named-string interpolation, the code would look like follows. Assuming the English-language error message is `Value 'x' is not a valid choice.`, we do:

```
expected_error = _("Value %(value)r is not a valid choice.") % {'value': 'x'}
self.assertEqual(expected_error, dict_err['category'][0])
```

I've found that the easiest way to determine the respective message ID is to search for the part of the English error message in the venv files. For example, I found the error above searching for "is not a valid choice", which is obviously an immutable part of the message.

Special thanks to @MosesKoledoye: his comment to my question hinted in the right direction.